# shiny sliderInput range minimum and maximum values

Tags: slider, shiny

I need to adjust a histogram output in shiny with a range values:

(where m is an arbitrary matrix)

```
#ui.R
sliderInput(inputId="adjust", label="Choose adjacency threshold", value=c(0.001, 0.9), min=0.0001, max=1),
plotOutput("hist")

#server.R
df<-reactive({
idx = m > min(input$adjust) & m < max(input$adjust)
    data.frame(
      id = row(m)[idx],
      value = m[idx])
})
output$hist<-renderPlot({hist(df()$values)})
```

However this doesn't seem to affect the histogram- it re-renders when I toggle the slider but its the same each time.... it takes a very long time and it just seems to take all of the values in into account?

Does anyone know how to make this work?

when I try to print the slider's min/max value- nothing comes to the page:

```
#ui.R
verbatimTextOutput("x")
#server
output$x<-renderPrint({min(input$adjust)})
```

Hence I might be approaching this the completely wrong way... does anyone know how to do this?

FULL EXAMPLE

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(ui = fluidPage(sliderInput(inputId="adjust", label="Choose adjacency threshold", value=c(0.001, 0.9), min=0.0001, max=1),
plotOutput("hist")
server=function(input, output){
   adjacentmat<-reactive({adjacency(dat)})
   data<-reactive({
    adj_mat<-adjacentmat()
    adj_mat[adj_mat < input$adjust] <- 0
    m<-adj_mat
    idx = m > min(input$adjust) & m < max(input$adjust)
    data.frame(
      source = row(m)[idx],
      target = col(m)[idx],
      corr = m[idx])
  })
  output$hist<-renderPlot({hist(data()$corr)})
}
)
```

generate the dat variable with the following code:

```
library('dplyr')
set.seed(1)

# generate a couple clusters
nodes_per_cluster <- 30
n <- 10

nvals <- nodes_per_cluster * n

# cluster 1 (increasing) 
cluster1 <- matrix(rep((1:n)/4, nodes_per_cluster) + 
                   rnorm(nvals, sd=1),
                   nrow=nodes_per_cluster, byrow=TRUE)

# cluster 2 (decreasing)
cluster2 <- matrix(rep((n:1)/4, nodes_per_cluster) + 
                   rnorm(nvals, sd=1),
                   nrow=nodes_per_cluster, byrow=TRUE)

# noise cluster
noise <- matrix(sample(1:2, nvals, replace=TRUE) +
                rnorm(nvals, sd=1.5),
                nrow=nodes_per_cluster, byrow=TRUE)

dat <- rbind(cluster1, cluster2, noise)
colnames(dat) <- paste0('n', 1:n)
rownames(dat) <- c(paste0('cluster1_', 1:nodes_per_cluster), 
                   paste0('cluster2_', 1:nodes_per_cluster),
                   paste0('noise_',    1:nodes_per_cluster))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(ui = fluidPage(
  mainPanel(sliderInput("test", "Select values", value= c(.001,.9), min= 0.0001, max= 1)),
  verbatimTextOutput("test2")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$test2 <- renderPrint(min(input$test))
  }))
```

I'm guessing your problem is somewhere in the code you haven't shown us. Can you give the code for the entire running example of your problem?

Comment: thanks Carl (I have updated the Q under FULL EXAMPLE) that actually works which means my code was valid however the pipeline takes really long to run now with the added requirement for the value of 'm' to be below a certain threshold as well as above another one... is there any way to get around this//